# ExpressJS Multiple session sharing local vs shared

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have some 30 different applications written in node js (expessjs). I am building single login for all, if user login into one app then he can access all other apps with one session, I am sharing session secret on all apps for that,

Problem is req.session is now shared with all apps, if any app store anything in session for local use of that app is also share will all apps,

I want to resolve this problem something like two sessions etc one can be shared will all apps and one for local use of that app.

Anyone have any idea please share.

Module used
express-session, cookie-parsor, redis-store

[MODIFIED]
Local data also need persistent, since few apps have multiple instances.
First case is session flash data
Second case is user permission details

Thanks

Comment: What type of data you want to keep per app? Is your data sensitive. Do you need persistence? Not knowing details of you app its difficult to answer. Since you are already using Redis maybe you can keep your app data in Redis.

Comment: Data is not sensitive but need persistent. First case is session flash data, second case is user permission details.

Comment: What do you mean by "session flash data"? For user permissions, maybe you want to keep the data in a database. That database could be as simple as a file or an actual database like MySql.

Comment: Like npm Connect-flash module for flash message for user there messages store in session.